# Is POCO multiprocessing library a wrapper?

Tags: multiprocessing, fork, poco, createprocess

Is the POCO multiprocessing library a wrapper around POSIX fork() and Windows' CreateProcess?

Considering I only have to use multiprocessing, is it worth using POCO? Does it have a modular structure that allows to pick bits and pieces individually?

Is it better to just use the platform specific libraries with conditional compilation?

Is there any other choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that Poco process class is carefully designed wrapper class for platform specific api.

You can checkout its code.

```
Process.h
Process_UNIX.h
Process_WIN32.h
Process_WINCE.h

#if defined(POCO_OS_FAMILY_WINDOWS) && defined(POCO_WIN32_UTF8)
#if defined(_WIN32_WCE)
#include "Process_WINCE.h"
#else
#include "Poco/Process_WIN32U.h"
#endif
#elif defined(POCO_OS_FAMILY_WINDOWS)
#include "Poco/Process_WIN32.h"
#elif defined(POCO_VXWORKS)
#include "Poco/Process_VX.h"
#elif defined(POCO_OS_FAMILY_UNIX)
#include "Poco/Process_UNIX.h"
#else
#include "Poco/Process_VMS.h"
#endif
```

You only need to link its Foundation library to your executable, so it has modular architecture.